# Contact form doesn't work with the new jQuery version (3.3.1)

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I was mistaken that I was missing anything from my PHP file. The only thing which makes the contact form working is if I use a way older version of the jQuery but that cannot be the case because I need SSL on my site and Google determines the site unsafe which wants to load unsafe scripts if they are older.

Here is the old version of the scripts:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

window.jQuery || document.write('</script>')

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And here is what I was trying to use. I downloaded js files and uploaded to the server but I thinks because of the many function changes my PHP file cannot do the work anymore.

Can somebody help me to update my PHP file because I don't really do coding :o. Tried to understand how it works however I got confused.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

---

I use a template from Styleshout called Kreative101 and modified it in many ways but I didn't touch the contact form nor the PHP file (only inserting the error reporting and the email address).

I don't know if it needs any jQuery script in order to work because I did change that and the Modal Popup stopped working. Now it is back to the original (at least the footer with the scripts). The modal works the contact form doesn't.

Any help will be highly appreciated;).

[If a reload the page says the action I took will be repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd0DL.jpg)

The contact form worked before, I tested it.

Here is the HTML code

```
<section id="contact">

      <div class="row section-head">
         <div class="col full">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p class="desc">Get in touch with us</p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">

         <div class="col g-7">

            <!-- form -->
            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
                    <fieldset>

                  <div>
                           <label for="contactName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                           <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" size="35" value="" />
                  </div>

                  <div>
                           <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                           <input name="contactEmail" type="text" id="contactEmail" size="35" value="" />
                  </div>

                  <div>
                           <label for="contactSubject">Subject</label>
                           <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" size="35" value="" />
                  </div>

                  <div>
                     <label  for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <textarea name="contactMessage"  id="contactMessage" rows="15" cols="50" ></textarea>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                     <button class="submit">Submit</button>
                     <span id="image-loader">
                        <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" />
                     </span>
                  </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </form> <!-- Form End -->

            <!-- contact-warning -->
            <div id="message-warning"></div>
            <!-- contact-success -->
                <div id="message-success">
               <i class="icon-ok"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br />
                </div>

         </div>
```

And the PHP code (I inserted the error reporting but I don't know if it's correct.)

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'info@virtualpropertyreview.com';


if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

   // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
   // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


   // Set Message
   $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
   $message .= "Message: <br />";
   $message .= $contact_message;
   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

   // Set From: header
   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

   // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


   if (!$error) {

      ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
      $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
      else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

Comment: `?<?php` at the very start is incorrect - presumably a copy/paste error. After sending the email use a `header` call to redirect the user ( to the same page )

Comment: yep, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment I suggested to redirect after sending the mail - not sure if you understood what I meant but like this.

```
$mail = mail( $siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers );
header('Location: ?mailsent=' . $mail ? 'true' : 'error' );
```

That should prevent the form being submitted if the page is reloaded accidentally etc

You could use that GET variable to display a message to report on status of the mail send.

```
if( !empty( $_GET['mailsent'] ) ){
    echo $_GET['mailsent']=='true' ? "your message was sent" : "Sorry, there was an error"; /* etc */
}
```

Comment: I understood it just didn't know how to do it. Thx for the extended answer but still nothing has changed. I really have a feeling that I am missing something somewhere else. I will dig deeper but first I will upload the original website under one of the domains I don't use and then I try if it works...if so I will figure it our from threre..;). cheers